# I have some errors on an discord.js bot im trying to make:

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, discord.js

error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
at Object.execute (/Users/Desktop/MSBTM/commands/ban.js:18:32)
at Client. (/Users/Desktop/MSBTM/bot.js:56:36)

---

And here is my the code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "ban peoples ;D",
    execute(message, args) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") || 
    !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have 
    a permissions to do this, maybe later ;)");

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const member = message.guild.member(user);

    const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please mention the user to make this action");

    if (user.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban yourself, I tried :(");
    if (user.id === client.user.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban me, I tried :(");

    if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided, please provide an reason to make this active";
      member.ban(reason).then(() => {
      message.channel.send(`Successfully banned **${user.tag}**`);
    }).catch(err => {
      message.reply("I was unable to ban the member :(");
    }) 
  } 
}
```

---

can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you create a `new` client object, which isn't logged in. I suggest you pass the client as a parameter to the function or use the `message.client` property. In the following example I used it as a function parameter:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "ban peoples ;D",
    execute(message, args, client) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") ||
            !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have a permissions to do this, maybe later ;) ");

        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        const member = message.guild.member(user);

        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please mention the user to make this action");

        if (user.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban yourself, I tried :(");
        if (user.id === client.user.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban me, I tried :(");

        if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided, please provide an reason to make this active";
        member.ban(reason).then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`Successfully banned **${user.tag}**`);
        }).catch(err => {
            message.reply("I was unable to ban the member :(");
        })
    }
}
```

You'd call this function like `execute(message, args, client)` then.

Comment: No problem! That's what this site is for

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a new Client instance does not provide you a Client.user right away.
Client.user gets populated when you login the ClientUser:

```
client.login('token');
```

Read more about it from [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#start-up-code-explained)

Comment: here is my bot: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tCjshzLadZeCu3Us33pDVgbP9By4QTsG?usp=sharing

Comment: One should be careful with that as this can lead to several instances of the bot listening to commands if these are not seperated precisely

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer does provide a better solution but I kept this here for the docs. Dependency Injection is definitely the way to go here.